# Combining youtube-dl and VLC without a pipe

Tags: json, vlc, youtube-dl

`youtube-dl -o - <webpage> | vlc -` shows a video in VLC. However, the video is *piped* (through something like `fd://0`), which inhibits the possibility to jump forwards/backwards.

However, `youtube-dl -j <webpage>` lists JSON data which contains several "url" properties. If you do `vlc <url>`, VLC now shows video length, lets us jump, etc. like if we were playing a local video.

Question: Now, it's perfectly possible to write a small Python script that extracts the URL, but is  there a simple way to do this using only simple Bash, preferably a one-liner?

Note: `youtube-dl -j` lists an array of video streams in different qualities, and it's desirable to pick the video with the highest quality.

Comment: To move on the stream, you need to store the file. The simple way: you create a temporary file (use `mktemp`), and you download the youtube video there. You feed the file to vlc. You remove the file (and because it is in `/tmp/`, if something go wrong, the file will be removed anyway.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi: Storing the file is not necessary, like written in the second paragraph. You can move on the file by using the technique described in the second paragraph.

Comment: I'm not understanding `vlc json->...->url`: are you meaning "get json from `youtube-dl`, parse it, extract one URL and feed that to `vlc`?

Comment: @fra-san: Correct!

Answer (score 12):

Parsing JSON in the shell is generally not a great idea. You can easily find that, on U&L, almost all the answers to questions along the lines of "how can I parse this JSON in the shell?" end up using specialized tools (e.g. [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) or [`jshon`](http://kmkeen.com/jshon/)).

This is why I suggest to leverage the ability of `youtube-dl` to select one video version when more than one is available and to print its URL on standard output instead of downloading it:

- `--format` or `-f`: lets you... specify a format. To have the highest quality, just specify `best`. Actually, in your case this is probably not required, because (see manual page `youtube-dl(1)`):

  > By default youtube-dl tries to download the best available quality
- `--get-url`, or `-g`, avoids downloading any video and only prints the URL of the selected one to standard output.

Then, leverage the ability of `vlc` to play (and seek) a video from URL. You can either pipe the URL to `vlc`:

```
youtube-dl --get-url --format best 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=video_id' | vlc -
```

or use command substitution to invoke `vlc` with the URL as argument:

```
vlc "$(youtube-dl --get-url --format best 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=video_id')"
```

Comment: Very nice! I can confirm that the latter solution works as expected. I hope others will find this useful! PS! It would be even better if there was a way to get subtitles support this way. I'm suspecting this will be a bit messy unless we can count on some developer support.

Comment: @forthrin Glad to hear that. Unfortunately I'm not aware of any way to let `vlc` get subtitles from Youtube (or anything else that is not a subtitles file).

Comment: Simple: You can do `vlc --sub-file video.srt video.mp4`. The question is how to get the subtitle file directly from `youtube-dl` directly on the command line, in a single go. I've requested support for this from the developers.